# echo the received value from JS getElementById in php

Tags: javascript, php

Regarding to this example

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_elements

Try to click "Submit" in the right side and you will receive this msg

(This page was returned to you from the server. The server has processed your input and returned this answer.)

I'm using the same example exactly and I need the code in php which echo the received values from javascript getElementById

How to GET and echo x.elements[i].value in php?

Comment: Simple HTML form that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $name => $value){
    echo $name . '=' . $value . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two files in the example you have mentioned.

1) HTML Page written in the tryit Editor.

2) An ASP page form_action.asp

you can find it here.

```
<form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
```

in your example.

So, In your client side you are sending the form data to the server.

And the server side ASP or PHP script will retrieve the form data and will echo it back.

if you have mentioned the form action as `form_action.php`
then 
Your PHP code:

`form_action.php`

```
<?php
$fname=$_GET['fname'];
$lname = $_GET['lname'];

echo $fname;
echo $lname;
?>
```